# String Index out of range python?

Tags: python, string, indexing, range, out

I am making a security login program in python, and I keep getting this error message: `IndexError: string index out of range.`

The error is for the line `character=password[c]`. I am at the part where it checks if the password that the user enters has a number. If it does not have a number, the password is invalid. How do I fix this?

```
while c<numbercharacters:
    character=password[c] 
    c=c+1
    while character!="1" and character!="2" and character!="3" and character!="4" and character!="5" and character!="6" and character!="7" and character!="8" and character!="9" and character!=0: #checking if password has a number
        print "This password is not valid, it does not contain a number. Please create another." 
        password= raw_input ()
        numbercharacters=len(password) 
        character=password[c]
```

`c` is the variable for the counter.

Comment: Fix indentation so we know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: And reorder the code, I think the first while should go after the numbercharacters=len(password)

Comment: `c` remains unchanged from the outer loop, so if the user re-enters a shorter password, c will become out of range.

Comment: One of these things is not like the others: `character != 0`

Comment: `not any(character.isdigit() for character in password)` or maybe `not set(password) & set(string.digits)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get fresh input for the password, due to it being invalid, you don't reset your counter `c` to zero to start the checking process from scratch again.

```
# After this block
password= raw_input ()
numbercharacters=len(password) 
# Reset your counter to zero
c = 0
character=password[c]
```

You can also simply for your character check for digits with either

```
while not character.isdigit():
# or 
while character not in '0123456789':
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is a number you can just do

```
password= raw_input ()
if not any(character.isdigit() for character in password):
    print "This password is not valid, it does not contain a number. Please create another."
```

If you want to re-ask for a password until it has a number

```
 password= raw_input ()
 if not any(character.isdigit() for character in password):
    while not any(character.isdigit() for character in password):
        print "This password is not valid, it does not contain a number. Please create another." 
        password= raw_input ()
```